# change the hash function in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and as far as I have studied, the documents are routed to a particular shard using a hash function.

Is there any way that I can the hash function so that the routing of the document is customized to my requirements?

The field to be considered in the hash function while routing can be changed using '_routing' field but is there any way to change the hash function altogether?